# Объединение выборок в 1 массив

Tags: массивы, php, выборка, mysql

Здравствуйте. 
Есть 4 выборки из 4-х таблиц - структура  таблиц идентичная, но с разными данными

Нужно объединить эти выборки в 1 общий массив. 
При этом должна соблюдаться сортировка, которая указывается при выборки (так же для всех выборок одинакова.)

Comment: Объединять нужно на сервере или на клиенте? В php, я думаю, массивы можно просто конкатенировать (кажется array_merge() или просто плюсом, как строки).

Про сортировку непонятно. Нужно состыковать массивы без пересортировки (т.е. из [a3,a2,a4] и [b1,b3,b2] получилось [a3,a2,a4,b1,b3,b2])? Это вроде как-раз плюсом делается.

Ну и вообще: гуголь: конкатенация массивов php

Comment: Подробнее и что за фишка с 4 одинаковыми таблицами?

Comment: Ну имеется ввиду, что структура у них одинаковая, но данные разные в них=)

Comment: array_merge()  не подходит именно из-за [a3,a2,a4,b1,b3,b2]

Вот смотрите. 
Во всех таблицах у меня есть столбец date, куда собственно и пишется дата. 

Нужно чтобы массив и делал вывод по дате. 

Тоесть:
[a3,b2,a4,a1,b3,b4] и т.д в зависимости от даты.

Comment: Т.е. если просто поставить таблицы одну за другой то порядок строк будет неправильный? Тогда либо сортировать в базе, как предложил @Pavel Volyntsev, либо опять-же средствами php, погуглите про сортировку массивов, там что-то такое было про сортировку по одному из элементов массивов.
Но вообще я скорее за сортировку в базе.

Comment: @RattleSneyk, одинаковая архитектура таблиц обычно говорит о том, что данные на самом деле должны лежать в одной, просто разделенные еще одним дополнительным признаком. Если ресурсы позволяют, лучше провести реструктуризацию БД.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такое объединение возможно на уровне запроса в базу данных. Посмотри на команду [UNION](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/UNION.html).
**Поверх** выборки по четырём таблицам можно выполнить сортировку. Посмотри на мануал по [подзапросам](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

На уровне PHP можно соединить массивы командой [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php). А затем отсортировать с помощью одной из [команд сортировки](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/array.sorting.php)